# How to solve "KeyError: "None of [Index(['Umur'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, matplotlib, plot

I have a [CSV file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dJ7aLqGTDhfpemIQpCYqR0PujLp2HrEH/view?usp=sharing) for the code I wrote.

I have an assignment to filter and plot data. I didn't really understand, so I just copied the code from my lecturer's presentation file, but I made the CSV file myself. When I tried to run the plot, it didn't work. This is what it said.

[image: This is what it said]

I want to make a bar chart to show the number of people with the same age. If it's possible, how do I make a pie chart instead, and show the percentage?

btw, "Umur" means Age

```
import pandas as pd

from pathlib import Path

df = pd.read_csv('inicsvanakbisdig.txt')
filepath = Path('tugaspertemuan12afk.csv')

df.to_csv(filepath)

#Column Selection
df1 = df['Nama']
print(df1)

#Select row where 'Umur' is equal to 20
df2 = df.loc[df['Umur'] == 20]
print(df2)

#Drop Kolom 'Umur'
df3 = df.drop(['Umur'], axis=1)
print(df3)

#Computes a summary of statistics
df4 = df.describe()
print(df4)

#Plot 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df5 = df.loc[['Umur']]

p = df5['Umur'].sort_index()
p.plot(kind = 'bar',title = 'Umur anak bisdig', xlabel = "Umur", ylabel = "Counter")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Single label in `loc` accesses row, you might want

```py
df5 = df.loc[:, ['Umur']]
# or
df5 = df[['Umur']]
```